# Why is split breaking up my words into characters

Tags: python, split

I have a csv file containing a parts list. The first column of the file is the part name followed by a series of numbers, and I would like to get rid of the trailing numbers so I just have the first word of the column. What I am trying to do is use the split function to break up the first column, then extract the first entry in the list and use that as the new column entry. I already have a good idea of how to do this, but for some reason my first column string is getting broken into individual characters.
I am putting in a csv file that has the following as an example:

```
Legs 1,53,1 3/4,2 1/2,
Fronts 3 1 1,1 1/2,1,27,
Sides 2 1,16 1/2,1,2 1/2,
```

Here is what I currently have for the code. All it is supposed to do is print the first word of the first column. In this case it would be

```
Legs
Fronts
Sides
```

Code:

```
import csv
```

input_file = 'Brook Field 4 Drawer.csv'

```
with open(input_file, 'rb') as infile:
    incsv = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in incsv:
        name_sorta = str(row[0])
        name_sorta.split()
        name = name_sorta[0]
        print name
```

What I am getting is

```
L
F
S
```

I am new to python so I'm sure I'm just making a simple mistake, but I can't quite figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` doesn't work in-place, because strings are immutable. You need to assign the result to something.

```
name_sorta = name_sorta.split()
```